Symfony compiler pass: Add a chained method to the service definition
I am writing a compiler pass in Symfony 5.4.
My goal is to disable a filter in the entity manager.
If you have an entity manager $em, you can do this with
$em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');

I need a way to describe that in the compiler pass:
class DisableSoftDeleteFilterCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $emDef = $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        
        // This will make the compiler run "$em->getFilters()" when building the service,
        // but I also need to call "disable('softdeleteable')" on the result of that call.
        $emDef->addMethodCall('getFilters', []);
    }
}

